# Change of program output on the basis of scanf statements in c

Tags: c

Consider my this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial (int number){
    if(number>1)
    return number*factorial(number-1);
}
int main() {
    int input;
    printf("Find the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("%d",factorial(input));
    return 0;
}
```

If the user inputs `1`, it outputs `1` and if the input is `0`, it returns `0`, though is was not supposed to, since `factorial()` function returns a garbage value. But, it works fine with other inputs, for example 2 outputs 2 and so on. Even if the user inputs some negatives like -2 or -3, it outputs the same value as the input. But somehow, if I comment the `scanf()` statements, then:

```
int main() {
   /* int input;
    printf("Find the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);*/
    printf("%d",factorial(0));
    return 0;
}
```

Then, it shows garbage value. For, a further change, let's look at this:

```
int main() {
    int input=-1;
    printf("%d",factorial(input));
    return 0;
}
```

Then, it does not return any garbage inputs anymore, rather it outputs `-1`. Is there such a case, that when an argument is passed to a function as a variable then if there is no `return` statement, it returns the value of the variable, that was passed as an argument. I did not find it anywhere.

Comment: When `if(number>1)` is false, what does your function then return? If you say that the function should return a value, then it *must* return a value, in all branches of execution. Your compiler should be complaining about missing `return` statement, you should listen to your compiler. And if you don't get a message about it, then you need to add more warnings when building.

Comment: "Is there such a case, that when an argument is passed to a function as a variable then if there is no return statement, it returns the value of the variable, that was passed as an argument." Not in C. Never heard of such an assumption.

Comment: "Is there such a case, that when an argument is passed to a function as a variable then if there is no return statement, it returns the value of the variable, that was passed as an argument." It is possible that the first parameter to the function and the return value are passed in the same CPU register. If you do not alter that value, it may occur that you get that value even if you do not have a `return` statement executed. That is not mandated by the C standard. It is undefined behaviour and of course, you should never rely on any such random behaviour.

Comment: Look up "undefined behavior".

Answer (score 1):

So you're trying to write a function that calculates the factorial of a given number and returns the same number if the number is negative. In your code, you're not covering the edge cases you're only returning when the number is greater than 1. I hope the below code will help you with your issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int factorial(int number) {
    if(number >= 1)
        return number * factorial(number - 1);
    if(number == 0)
        return 1;
    return number; // returns same number if number is negative
}

int main() {
    int input;
    printf("Find the factorial of: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    printf("%d", factorial(input));
    return 0;
}
```

So above code will provide the correct output for numbers less than and equal to 16 and for numbers above 16 it will return the garbage value as we are storing the output in `int` allowing it to represent integer values in the range of `-2147483648 to 2147483647`.

Comment: This was not what I was looking for. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Could you please update your question for better understanding ?

Comment: "for numbers above 16 it will return the garbage value" --> Maybe, maybe not.  When `number * factorial(number - 1)` overflows, that incurs _undefined behavior_ (UB) and anything may happen including program stopping.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there such a case, that when an argument is passed to a function as a variable then if there is no return statement, it returns the value of the variable, that was passed as an argument

No.

Failure to return a value and the calling codes needs that value  is not defined, so you get *undefined behavior*.   The result *might* be what is desired, might not.

---

Tip: Enable all compiler warnings to quickly identify such bad code.